# Default Value Of Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, trigger, update

In my example syntax below I want the field `delayed` to be the difference in days between `gotitdate` and `dunitdate`  I know that this syntax will get me the result, and I was going to set this up as an `OnInsert()` and a `AfterUpdate()` trigger **however** my two fields are not required!  I can not alter table structure to make them be required.

Question at hand, how can I use this update syntax to account for a null date, to update to 0 if either field is null or update to the `DateDiff()` if both fields are not null?  And as always, if there is a better approach for this methodology I am open to suggestions:

```
Create Table #Moofasa
(
  gotitdate date
  ,dunitdate date
  ,delayed int
)

Insert Into #Moofasa (gotitdate, dunitdate) Values
('07/01/2016','07/05/2016')
,('07/01/2016','07/04/2016')
,('07/04/2016','07/08/2016')

Update #Moofasa 
Set delayed = DateDiff(d, gotitdate, dunitdate)
WHERE delayed is null

Select * from #Moofasa

--Drop Table #Moofasa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx) would solve the issue and probably be better than having triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE #Moofasa
(
  gotitdate DATE,
  dunitdate DATE,
  delayed AS COALESCE( DATEDIFF(day, gotitdate, dunitdate), 0)
) ;
```

Tested at: [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/WMH20331):

```
INSERT INTO #Moofasa 
  (gotitdate, dunitdate) 
VALUES
  ('2016-07-01', '2016-07-05'),
  ('2016-07-01', '2016-07-04'),
  ('2016-07-04', '2016-07-08'),
  (NULL,         '2016-07-09'),
  ('2016-07-09', NULL),
  (NULL,         NULL)  ;

SELECT * 
FROM #Moofasa ;
```

gives:

```
gotitdate   dunitdate   delayed
01.07.2016  05.07.2016  4 
01.07.2016  04.07.2016  3 
04.07.2016  08.07.2016  4 
NULL        09.07.2016  0
01.07.2016  NULL        0
NULL        NULL        0
```